# Get Json data from controller

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I need to create dinamic select into my form.
I have wrote this code to get it dinamically from my controller (CodeIgniter) that get data from model.

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("select#regione").change(function(){
                        $.getJSON("http://test:8888/ricerca/test",{id: $(this).val()}, function(dati){
                            var options = '';
                            for (var i = 0; i < dati.length; i++) {
                                options += '<option value="' + dati[i].valore + '">' + dati[i].etichetta + '</option>';
                            }
                            $("#provincia").html(options);
                            $('#provincia option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

This is the dropdown form:

```
<form action="base_url().'ricerca'" method="post">
<select name="regione" id="regione">
<option value="">No option</option>
<option value="Lombardia">Lombardia</option>
<option value="Lazio">Lazio</option>
</select>

<select name="provincia" id="provincia">
</select>
</form>
```

and this is the controller:

```
class Ricerca extends CI_Controller
{
 public function test()
{
 $dati = array();
         array_push($dati,array("valore"=>"ciao", "etichetta"=>"ciao"));
         array_push($dati,array("valore"=>"mamma", "etichetta"=>"mamma"));
         return json_encode($dati);
}
}
```

Before to do my query in the model I would see if my script works but if I select an option in the first select called "Regione" the script does nothing

Comment: use a browser console to see if the request is being made and if any general script errors are thrown. If request is made...what is being sent and received? Need better clues than "does nothing".

Comment: I have tried to see if firebug's console could help but it doesn't show any error, it does't see the script at all

Comment: show js as it is output in source and you haven't answered if request is being made in firebug. looks like you have problems at both client and server

Comment: The output is the same I have wrote in the question, firebug doen't see my script, if I change the select in the console firebug doen't see it

Comment: in your get json what is $url can you tell me

Comment: is http://test:8888/ricerca/test is on my local machine

Comment: found the problem, is a conflict with this plugin: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/ if I remove it the json data works!
I need to find a way to make it work togheter now...

Answer (score 0):

you have to echo json data from controller function not to return data

```
public function test()
{
 $dati = array();
         array_push($dati,array("valore"=>"ciao", "etichetta"=>"ciao"));
         array_push($dati,array("valore"=>"mamma", "etichetta"=>"mamma"));
         echo json_encode($dati);
}
```

or you can do

```
public function test()
    {
     $dati = array();
             array_push($dati,array("valore"=>"ciao", "etichetta"=>"ciao"));
             array_push($dati,array("valore"=>"mamma", "etichetta"=>"mamma"));
             $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($dati));
    }
```

Comment: ound the problem, is a conflict with this plugin: abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin if I remove it the json data works! I need to find a way to make it work togheter now..